# Initiate a private phone call for both side in Android app

Tags: android, anonymous, conversation-scope

I am building an Android app and want to initiate an anonymous phone call for both caller and receiver.

For example:

User A press 'call User B' button, and then initiate an anonymous phone call to User B. The tricky point is that both User A and B don't know each other's phone number and after the conversation, there is no record left and privacy is protected.

I don't know if native Android can do this. Could anyone give me some clues about this? Thank you very much!

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the platform source-code there is NO WAY to place a call without the knowledge of the user. The best thing you can do is to make the call automatically but the user will see a dialog saying: "Calling XXXXXXXX" and he will have the chance to cancel it.

Even if you make your own dialer application you will have to sign it with the system key and place it in the system/apps folder in order to get the required permissions for that kind of things.

As for the call log, I don't know if you can make the call not to appear in it in the first place but I think (not sure though) that you can find it and deleted afterwards. Android informs other applications of call actions via Intents so it is relative easy to detect when a call ended and then query the call log.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hello Ngima, thanks for your comment and explanation. I understand it is impossible to carry out my idea by working on the platform source-code now.

Is there any way to accomplish my goal? For example via VOIP or some other tools or service, so to keep the privacy of both side to be safe but they still make phone calls to each other?